# Autofill state while user enter zip code by using zip code database|Django|JQuery|UI

Tags: html, jquery, django

How to auto fill state by entering zip code. I have zip code database. How to validate with in form. If user enters the zip code that zip code is available in this database using that zip code the state should autofill as mention below datbase. If zip code matches then state must autofill.

I have implemented this using API. But know I have to do with database:

```
    INSERT INTO pages_zip_code (id, zip, city, st) VALUES
    (1, '00501', 'Holtsville', 'NY'),
    (2, '00544', 'Holtsville', 'NY'),
    (3, '00601', 'Adjuntas', 'PR'),
    (4, '00602', 'Aguada', 'PR'),
    (5, '00603', 'Aguadilla', 'PR'),
    (6, '00604', 'Aguadilla', 'PR'),
    (7, '00605', 'Aguadilla', 'PR'),
    (8, '00606', 'Maricao', 'PR'),
    (9, '00610', 'Anasco', 'PR'),
    (10, '00611', 'Angeles', 'PR'),
    (11, '00612', 'Arecibo', 'PR'),
    (12, '00613', 'Arecibo', 'PR'),
    (13, '00614', 'Arecibo', 'PR'),
    (14, '00616', 'Bajadero', 'PR'),
    (15, '00617', 'Barceloneta', 'PR'),
    (16, '00622', 'Boqueron', 'PR');
```

**urls.py**`

```
    path('autostate', views.autostate, name='autostate'),
```

**views.py**

```
    def autozip(request):
    if 'term' in request.GET:
    qs = zip_code.objects.filter(zip__istartswith=request.GET.get('term'))
    zip_list = list()
    for zip_c in qs:
    zip_list.append(zip_c.state)
    return JsonResponse(zip_list, safe=False)
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

**html page**

```html
<input class="InputZip" name="Zip" placeholder="Zip Code" type="text">
<input class="Inputstate" name="state" placeholder="State" type="text">
```

```
    <script>
    function is_int(value) {
    if ((parseFloat(value) == parseInt(value)) && !isNaN(value)) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
    }
    $(".InputZip").keyup(function() {
    // Cache
    var el = $(this);
    // Did they type five integers?
    if ((el.val().length == 5) && (is_int(el.val()))) {
    // Call Ziptastic for information
    $.ajax({
    url: '{% url 'autostate' %}',
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(result, success) {
    $(".Inputstate").val(result.state_short);
    },
    });
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: The indentations for your `views.py` file are unclear. Please check if I interpreted your indentations correctly.

Comment: The indentation is absolutely correct.

Comment: The list `zip_li` is never used in your view. Why are you building that list? Did you want to pass it to the template or use it in the view?

Comment: Actually i have tried that but i ma unable to get the answer. if you have an idea plz modify it for me

Comment: I have modify the code you can see actually i forgot to return zip_list